# Using fabric8io kubernetes-client; is it possible to remove a [custom] watcher?

Tags: java, kubernetes-health-check

Watcher:

```
private final class CustomKubeWatcher implements Watcher<Pod> { ... }
```

Added using:

```
kubeClient.pods().inNamespace(kubeNamespace).watch(customKubeWatcher);
```

How do I stop the watcher? Does it get cleaned up when my client instance is GC'd?

https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, `watch()` will return a [`Watch` object](https://static.javadoc.io/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client/2.4.1/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Watch.html), which can be [closed](https://static.javadoc.io/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client/2.4.1/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Watch.html#close--).

Comment: Thank you. I have found the same after reading the API docs for a bit. It's strange none of the examples demo this usage.